# ModelChoiceFilter is throwing error in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have following Filter class.

```
class CallSummaryFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    ringing_mobile_number = filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=CallSummary.objects.all(),method='filter_mobile_number')

    class Meta:
        model = CallSummary
        fields = ('caller', 'callee')

    def filter_mobile_number(self, queryset, name, value):
        queryset = queryset.filter(Q(caller=value) | Q(callee=value))
        return queryset
```

Request Format :- http://127.0.0.1:8000/call-summaries/?ringing_mobile_number=1234567890

it's throwing following error.

{'ringing_mobile_number': [ErrorDetail(string='Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.', code='invalid_choice')]}

Comment: What values did you give as input to the filter?

Comment: ringing_mobile_number=1234567890

Comment: and if issue is related to values then serializer will throw the error like invalid input type.